# How to have React Native project versions seamless across project and platforms

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

It is very annoying to change build version of my React Native (not Expo) application every time I build it.

It needs to be changed in at leats 4 places at moment:

- /android/app/build.gradle
- /ios/*projectname*/Info.plist
- package.json
- My config file (But I think I can handle this by loading it from package.json)

Is there any way to automatize this? For example every place gets updates when package.json version changes?

Comment: Any suggestion to do it for info.plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android you could have in `/android/build.gradle` a function:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def getNPMVersion() {
    def file = new File("$rootDir/../package.json")
    def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(file.text)
    return packageJson["version"]
}
```

and then in your `/android/app/build.gradle` you'd use `versionName getNPMVersion()`

For ios I'm pretty sure you'll need a script that overrides the `Info.plist`